# Ubuntu - MonoGame static graphics.Viewport size

Tags: ubuntu, graphics, monodevelop, viewport, monogame

I'm running MonoGame in MonoDevelop under Ubuntu and doing some tutorials, but I'm constantly experiencing a problem with the size of

```
graphics.Viewport
```

Each time I build an app, it doesn't matter if it is windowed or fullscreen. The resolution doesn't matter also.

```
graphics.Viewport.Width
graphics.Viewport.Height
```

always return 800x480. Does anyone has any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I still don't know what was causing the problem, but I managed to avoid it. I was trying to get

```
graphics.Viewport.Width
graphics.Viewport.Height
```

in a

```
protected override void LoadContent()
```

function. That's where the values were wrong. I tested some options and it came out that in the game class constructor, the values are right so what I did was simply I called a class attribute

```
int[] WindowSize;
```

and then in the main class constructor

```
WindowSize = new int[] {graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,
                        graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height};
```

and that's what fixed my problem with the window size.